# D3 Slice array with from to values

Tags: d3.js

I have a dataset like below,

```
const data = [
    {frequency: 600, letter: 0, luminous: 234},
    {frequency: 2456, letter: 13, luminous: 4000},
    {frequency: 1200, letter: 2, luminous: 1402},
    {frequency: 1400, letter: 3, luminous: 1500},
    {frequency: 1234, letter: 4, luminous: 1800},
    {frequency: 768, letter: 5, luminous: 1900},
    {frequency: 3456, letter: 9, luminous: 2300},
    {frequency: 4567, letter: 10, luminous: 670},
    {frequency: 600, letter: 6, luminous: 2233},
    {frequency: 350, letter: 7, luminous: 1450},
    {frequency: 2340, letter: 8, luminous: 1470},
    {frequency: 4200, letter: 11, luminous: 5600},
    {frequency: 3000, letter: 12, luminous: 4500},
    {frequency: 1200, letter: 14, luminous: 4200},
    {frequency: 1100, letter: 15, luminous: 3000},
    {frequency: 1700, letter: 16, luminous: 4500},
];
```

and I need to slice this array data with from value and 2 value with d3

```
const maxLetter = d3.max(data, d => d.letter);
const width = 400;
const scaleX = scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, maxLetter])
    .range([0, width])
    .clamp(true)
```

is it possible to slice my `data` array with starting `letter = 2` to end`letter = 9` everything between this range as a new array? like below with d3?

```
const newData = [
    {frequency: 1200, letter: 2, luminous: 1402},
    {frequency: 1400, letter: 3, luminous: 1500},
    {frequency: 1234, letter: 4, luminous: 1800},
    {frequency: 768, letter: 5, luminous: 1900},
    {frequency: 600, letter: 6, luminous: 2233},
    {frequency: 350, letter: 7, luminous: 1450},
    {frequency: 2340, letter: 8, luminous: 1470},
    {frequency: 3456, letter: 9, luminous: 2300}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do it with a simple loop?
Like this:

```
var newData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if(data[i].letter >= 2 && data[i].letter < 10){
    newData.push(data[i]);
  }
}
```

To get the `newData` array ordered by `letter` you could use a comparator:
`newData.sort((a, b) => a.letter - b.letter)`

Answer (score 0):

To perform operations on data, **[Crossfilter](https://github.com/square/crossfilter)** is best solution.

- Feed data into crossfilter
- Create dimension based on the key *[letter]*
- Use **[filterRange](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference)** to filter out the data

```js
const data = [
    {frequency: 600, letter: 0, luminous: 234},
    {frequency: 2456, letter: 13, luminous: 4000},
    {frequency: 1200, letter: 2, luminous: 1402},
    {frequency: 1400, letter: 3, luminous: 1500},
    {frequency: 1234, letter: 4, luminous: 1800},
    {frequency: 768, letter: 5, luminous: 1900},
    {frequency: 3456, letter: 9, luminous: 2300},
    {frequency: 4567, letter: 10, luminous: 670},
    {frequency: 600, letter: 6, luminous: 2233},
    {frequency: 350, letter: 7, luminous: 1450},
    {frequency: 2340, letter: 8, luminous: 1470},
    {frequency: 4200, letter: 11, luminous: 5600},
    {frequency: 3000, letter: 12, luminous: 4500},
    {frequency: 1200, letter: 14, luminous: 4200},
    {frequency: 1100, letter: 15, luminous: 3000},
    {frequency: 1700, letter: 16, luminous: 4500},
];

const CFX = crossfilter(data);
const dimension = CFX.dimension(function (d){ return d.letter; });

console.dir(dimension.top(Infinity).length);
dimension.filterRange([2, 10]);

console.dir(dimension.top(Infinity));
console.dir(dimension.top(Infinity).length);
```

```html
<script src="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
```